# How holding force is produced in Jacobs taper for holding drill chucks?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, machining, machine-design

How the wedge action produce significant holding force in a Jacobs taper for holding a twist drill chuck.
(Even just sliding the tapered plug inside the sleeve by hand makes a rigid connection that it's difficult to remove again by hand)

Comment: You are asking about the Jacobs taper? If so, you can edit the  question title and body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just friction due to high pressure from the wedge effect. It's not like the pull out force that a Jacobs taper must withstand is very high; It just needs to stop the drill chuck from dropping out under its own weight. It won't withstand machine forces trying to pull the taper out.

The real force that the taper must withstand is the drilling force which pushes into the taper and that is pushing the wedge in so it's no surprise why that works.